# Outlook REST API calls return internal server error 500

Tags: api, rest, outlook, outlook-restapi, http-status-code-500

When using the Microsoft Outlook REST API to make calls to my own Outlook Calendar, I receive an internal server error 500.  My access tokens are apparently fine and everything, but I still get this error.  I thought there might be a problem somewhere in my script, but I get the error even when using the [Outlook OAuth Sandbox](https://oauthplay.azurewebsites.net/).  I understand that certain Outlook accounts are not REST API-enabled yet, but according to the [documentation](https://dev.outlook.com/restapi/getstarted),

> making API calls to mailboxes that are not yet upgraded will return a
>   MailboxNotEnabledForRESTAPI or MailboxNotSupportedForRESTAPI error
>   code.

I do not receive those error codes.  So does anyone know what the problem might be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry to hear that you're having this problem. We recently discovered a scenario where Outlook.com accounts that haven't been migrated onto the REST-enabled platform will get this error instead of the expected MailboxNotEnabledForRESTAPI or MailboxNotSupportedForRESTAPI code. It sounds like your account hasn't been migrated yet. This is a problem on our side in that we're not returning the correct error.

In the meantime if you need an account to test against, if you create a new account it should be REST-enabled right away.

Comment: Thanks a lot.  You just responded to my email, too, so I appreciate that.  Is there any way to expedite the migration of my account?  I'd set up a new one, but I have so much tied up in my current account (Office activation, extra Onedrive storage), that I don't really want to move to a new one.  Thanks again.

Comment: Did you update the Python Outlook API tutorial recently?  It's got some serious problems.  There's missing imports, and at one point somebody just copied and pasted some C code in there. (example: if (current_token && now < expiration):  // Token still valid)  Somebody needs to test these tutorials before they're posted.

Comment: I also asked a question here that might be relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39945000/format-vs-concatenate-urls.  Apparently the urllib module should be used to join those url parts.